# Books about teaching at university following quality standards?

Tags: teaching, books

What introductory books are there for a new university lecturer to know about teaching with quality assurance in mind?

Comment: This question is likely going to be closed as a ['shopping question'](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/why-was-my-question-put-on-hold-for-shopping). There are many many books on university teaching. Narrowing by subject/discipline may help somewhat. Do you have any specific questions about university teaching that could be answered?

Comment: @atom44 updated and edited

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know exactly what you are wanting to discover but two books I have found useful and interesting are:

- *A Handbook for Teaching and Learning in Higher Education: Enhancing academic practice* -- edited by Marshall, Fry and  Ketteridge
- *Quality Assurance in Higher Education: Contemporary Debates* --- edited by Rosa and Amaral

They are both about 10 years old now, so the "contemporary" in "contemporary debates" might not be quite what is at the cutting edge now!